# Is it possible to login to multiple facebook accounts? (C# 4.0)

Tags: c#, facebook, c#-4.0

I am creating a small desktop application, which would ideally allow multiple facebook users to log in. After they play a game (on one machine), I'd like to be able to individually post their status to their Facebook accounts. This is possible if there is just a single user, but multiple users are causing problems with Sessions and so on. Can anyone advise a way to get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better answer your question, it would help to know how exactly you're connecting to Facebook from your game software.

In general, if you're using OAuth tokens to do it, try keeping separate sets of access tokens and pass along each one when appropriate.

Comment: I am using OAuth tokens to do it, but in order to get an OAuth token, we have to direct the user to the Facebook login screen. However, if there is someone else already logged in, that user's data shows up and if that data logs out, the token becomes invalidated.

Comment: Depending on how your in-app browser implementation, you MIGHT be able to go move the cookie away for safekeeping where the browser can't get to it and then swap it back when that user is needed again.  They certainly don't stop multiple sessions from the same machine itself, as one can see by logging in via Chrome and then again with a Chrome incognito window.